# Resolve host of `http::uri::Uri` to IP addresses

Tags: rust, dns

I have an [`http::uri::Uri`](https://docs.rs/http/latest/http/uri/struct.Uri.html) value and I want to get the `IpAddr`s of the host. In case the host is an IP address (e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8080`), it just needs to be parsed. But if it's a hostname, it needs to be DNS resolved. How do I best do that?

It seems like `std` only has one public way to resolve hosts: [`ToSocketAddrs`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/trait.ToSocketAddrs.html). Unfortunately, it includes the port in the API which is irrelevant for DNS resolving. But oh well. But with this, my first attempt was thus:

```
use std::net::ToSocketAddr;

let host = uri.authority().unwrap().host();
let addresses = (host, 0).to_socket_addrs()?
    .map(|socket_addr| socket_addr.ip());
```

(I am using a dummy port here since it's irrelevant for the DNS resolution.)

This attempt works for many cases, but not for the square-bracket IPv6 form: `http://[::1]:8080`. Here, `host()` is `[::1]` and is not parsable as `IpAddr`, thus `to_socket_addrs()` tries to resolve `[::1]` as host, which fails. So I would need to check manually whether the host is an IPv6 within square-brackets. Not nice, especially since I don't know what grammars are allowed here exactly.

I had several other ideas, like changing the `Authority` to always have a dummy port, because then I could call `authority.as_str().to_socket_addrs()`. The `<&str as ToSocketAddr>` does support the `[::1]:8080` syntax! But that impl NEEDS a port and fails if there is none.

So yes, I have not found an easy way to do that. But it seems this should not be that hard! Any ideas?

Comment: It's seem std is missing a valid representation of ipv6 in host_name `[ipv6]` is a valid hostname and should be parsed by `to_socket_addrs()`. see `IPv6reference  =  "[" IPv6address "]"` in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261.html

Comment: maybe try https://lib.rs/crates/trust-dns-resolver or https://lib.rs/crates/dns-lookup ?

Comment: @Stargateur That is the RFC for SIP. `to_socket_addrs()` has nothing to do with SIP.

Comment: @cdhowie sip rfc and abnf is based on http that more or less the same, it's standard to use this abnf for http too (even if there is some fix in other rfc notably for ipv6 abnf)

Comment: @Stargateur But `to_socket_addrs()` has nothing to do with HTTP either. I'm not sure why it should support bracketed-IPv6 notation. This is a detail of a higher-level protocol like HTTP/SIP, of which `to_socket_addrs()` is (understandably) ignorant. This is like expecting POSIX `getaddrinfo()` to support bracketed-IPv6 notation. These functions operate closer to the transport layer, while the representation of IPv6 with square brackets is a detail of the application layer.

Comment: @cdhowie [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.2) is the protocol-agnostic standard for URIs and it clearly defines how IPv6 addresses should be handled.

Comment: @cdhowie if you have a better doc I all hear, as Jmb link the RFC 3986 fix the abnf for hostname of RFC 3261 (also https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5954), that the standard ALL peoples use since 20 years. And trust me I HATE ipv6 text representation of this RFC so I don't say this happy, but that how it is, if this is not what rust follow so what rust follow ? so as I said, it's seems std forget to handle a case [ip] period

Comment: Again, `to_socket_addrs()` is lower-level than URIs. Not sure why this is controversial. Having said that, it's also unlikely to be the ideal mechanism to resolve hostnames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try parsing it as [`std::net::IpAddr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.IpAddr.html#impl-FromStr) first, then look up the hostname if that fails.  You have to handle the square bracket notation yourself, but this isn't too bad:

```
use std::net::IpAddr;

fn parse_ip_from_uri_host(host: &str) -> Option<IpAddr> {
    host.parse::<IpAddr>().ok().or_else(||
        // Parsing failed, try as bracketed IPv6
        host.strip_prefix("[")?
            .strip_suffix("]")?
            .parse::<IpAddr>().ok()
    )
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=de2075e598110101b42b435205c9a59e))

If this returns `None` then parsing failed, and the next step is to attempt to resolve the string as a hostname through DNS.

Comment: I've done it slightly differently, but still manually. So yeah, thanks for "this isn't too bad" to finally get me to just write it down.